# How to get a Gyro chain?

Tags: gyromancer

I have tried to get a gyro chain a few times in Gyromancer, but never really could pull it out. More often than not, I would just starve out of moves that didn't involve damaging the enemy, which doesn't help when you have to make so many moves in a row. Things get worse if either monster starts throwing locks on the board.

What's a good matchup (own monster and enemy monster) and a good strategy for attaining a gyro chain?

Comment: Yes, I have seen [this video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5G3ttOHmSE), but the player does use a lot of items to eventually get there. I wonder if there are easier or more effective ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Gyro Chain is when you reach Level 6 on the chain meter.   You'll see "5" and then fill the meter all the way one more time.  The chain meter increases each time you make a move which matches gems, and decreases **a lot** each time you make an Idle Twist (a move where no gems are cleared).

You can reduce your effective level by using a monster with a low level cap; battles will be fought at the monster's capped level.

For both your beast and your opponent, avoid beasts that generate locks (most important) and (if possible) stones.  Try to get use a beast with the following properties:

- Ability which clears stones, if your opponent generates stones
- Ability which clears locks, if your opponent generates locks.  (But, it's really much easier not to attempt this against an enemy that generates locks.)
- Ability which destroys enemy Ability gems
- Ability which changes all the color of some gems to another color.  (This is useful for creating **more moves**.)
- Not too powerful.  (You can choose a beast with a lower level cap.)

I've had the most success taking in an **Edomasaur**; his Gulp ability destroys stones.  I got up to a level 5 chain using Edomasaur without using any items.

Try to save all of your Magic Mirrors for doing a Gyro Chain.  (This item will allow you to twist, once, in the opposite direction.) Magick Keys will also be useful if you have Locks on the board.  Consider making a copy of your save game, as the game may autosave if you finish a battle; including one where you've used your items.

I recommend going up against **Paleofungus** because they are strong and focus on healing themselves.  There are a few in Level 50 Paleofungi in the Grove of Prey.

Answer (score 3):

This is incredibly tricky to pull off and from what I hear, and pretty much impossible to do without lots of Magic Mirror items on hand. Do not fight a monster that uses locks! You have to have a good idea of your own damage output and the damage output of your opponent so you know what kinds of hits you can take and what ones you'll want to take care of and match to delete. You don't want to pick a monster that's too easy either, as you'll end up wiping the floor with them before you can make all your matches.

Apparently in Stage 6, if you fight against the level 20 Paleofungus, you have a good chance, according to [this link](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/rpg/gyromancer/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-52388623&pid=974793). I remembering reading that recommendation in other places back when I was looking for info on this, but I can't find sources at the moment. Hope this helps!

Comment: It may not help that I have a level 70 character right now :)